# How to handle login pages in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm login to the application using REST call done by the angular code, like this:

```
request.success(function (html) {
       $scope.username = html.success.username
       $scope.userLoggedIn = true;
       $location.path("/home");
            })
```

It will redirect to the `/home`, where I'm showing my contents, which is working expected.

Now in the .html files I have this:

```
<div ng-view ng-show="userLoggedIn"></div>
<div class="modal-body" ng-show="!userLoggedIn"> Login page contents </div>
```

so that based on login success, I can show my `/home` page.

The problem being is, when the user refreshes the page, even though I have session (got from login first), its taking me to the login page as `userLoggedIn` is loosing its value.

How should I handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest these two approaches, that I got in my head right now:

**first option:**

- Create a service for authentication
- Set up a flag there (Ex: isloggedIn)
- inject the service in your controller
- if the user is authenticated do a redirect to home
- the service should read the information from a cookie.

**second option**

- Create a service for authentication
- Set up a flag there (Ex: isloggedIn)
- Do a full page redirect when authenticated
- Write the user information in your HTML using your backend (after authentication)
- The service should read the information from the window object

  *since you are doing a full page redirection you'll have no problems with the page refresh

this is an example:

```
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [
    function() {
        var _this = this;
        var user = window.user;
        _this._data = {
            user: user,
            isloggedIn: function(){
                return this.user !== null && this.user !== undefined;
            }
        };
        return _this._data;
    }
]);
```

your markup should look like this, near your open body tag :
   (write this script with your middleware php, asp.net, node, rails, etc)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var user = {"_id":"someID","displayName":"jack.the.ripper" }; //your user object should be here as json
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that should help me here. I tried the first approach, getting the cookie from the browser like this `$cookieStore.JSESSIONID` and also `$cookieStore.get("JSESSIONID")`, but both returning me `undefined` but I can see in my console, cookie is being set.

Comment: make sure your cookie httpOnly has been set to false and you can access it from the client, I'm just posting this article as pure reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok I understood. Since I'm new to the Angular, which method you prefer me?

Comment: either way that depends on you needs, I'm my opinion I'd stick to option number 2 do a full page request to a private page just feels better for me, but again it's up to you! good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you can use many local storage system to conserve your user when his connected like window.localstorage, cookies and many others.

If you want to test if the user is connected when refreshing, you can use

```
app.run(function(){
// launch when page is refreshed
});
```

at the bottom of your main angular app declaration